# 'float' object is not subscriptable error when using pandas to extract data from cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am importing a CSV file and I want to look at the `school_hours` column and extract the starting hours. Here are the first few lines from the column (you can assume that the data is already imported)

[image]

Essentially, I want to create a new column named `starting_hours` that should look something like this:

[image]

This is the following code that I wrote:

```
df['starting_hours']= [i[0:5] for i in df.School_Hours.str.split(' ').values]
```

I keep getting a `'float' object is not subscriptable` error

Comment: When asking your first question, consider learning on how to ask. images are discouraged. consider posting data in text form

Answer (score 0):

You can try `str.split` then access the first element of list with `str[0]`

```py
df['starting_hours'] = df['School_Hours'].str.split('-').str[0].str.strip('AM|PM')
```

```
print(df)

      School_Hours starting_hours
0  08:00AM-O3:00PM          08:00
```